# ASP.Net MVC Routing Empty Default Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

**SUMMARY:**

I'm reviewing the route mapping for a site I've recently begun work on. I've encountered a route that I'm not familiar with:

`RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(NamedRoutes.ROUTE_NAME, "urlSegment1/urlSegment2", new { });`

Notice that the "default" parameter for MapRoute is an empty object. This is normally where I would specify my controller, action, and any parameters. I've been googling around and am finding that I'm not asking the right questions to produce the answer I'm looking for.

**QUESTION:**

How does MVC routing behave when  the "defaults" parameter of MapRoute is an empty object? An answer would be great. Supporting docs would be even better.

**EDIT:**

The actual route being used is:

```
routes.MapRoute(NamedRoutes.BROWSE_MEN, "browse/Mens", new { } });
```

And the problem is occurring when generating the URL using:

```
Html.BeginForm("Add", "Signup", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "signup", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

Comment: Does the route in-fact work? I almost see this as a way of killing a route that was previously used.

Comment: It works, yes. However, the problem I'm having is that I'm expecting a route to get hit that is mapped below this route. I'm finding that anything below this route is not getting hit and everything is getting caught by this route.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is a constraint not a default

Comment: move this route to the bottom.  It looks like it may be intended to be a catch all route

Comment: @Brian. I agree that it is working as a catch all. I'm just trying to understand how it's working. More specifically, why would an inbound request of ABC/DEF hit a route pattern of urlSegment1/urlSegment2?

Comment: @Sruly. Thanks for the recommendation. I'm really not looking to make a change here. I'm just trying to understand how routing behaves in the context I've described.

Comment: It shouldn't act as a catch all, all it should do is guarantee a 404 if you try to go to that url. May you post the other routes just in case those are causing the error? (I did a quick test in an mvc app and it basically acted like the route wasn't there)

Comment: The route you have described in the question is not valid. You should have a controller and action segments either they appear in the url segments or in defaults, neither in your case! I'm just wondering how it's working for you. Would you mind posting the real route?

Comment: @Mark I think the point is that it doesn't work. But still, if I test it myself, I only see an impact if it matches part of a lower route's url (i.e. bad route: "search/run" would break good route: "search/run/{controller}/{action}" if it were below it.)

Comment: @parKing you made the question clear :)

Answer (score 0):

They are mapped as stings and in this case matches everything. The defaults are only there if one of the controller/action parameters are not supplied by the url. In this case no defaults are meaningless. It is actually catching everything string/string.

Answer (score 0):

The route you have there is will match a request that contains exactly the two segments in the url ex. `http://localhost/urlSegment1/urlSegment2` and returns a 404. I guess you have this route defined to avoid the following routes handle this request.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify a controller, either as URL parameter (token) or default value, you should get an InvalidOperationException:

> The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which
>   is required.

Same for action. That is for incoming request. For URL generation there's no requirement for controller or action.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to specify defaults.

So it works as if there were no default object specified

Comment: So, I should expect the framework to look for a controller named "urlSegment1"?

Comment: No. There is no controller set here at all. This route should not do anything. if your want segment1 to be your controller you would type {Controller}/segment2

Comment: OK, thanks. However, this doesn't explain why an inbound request of ABC/DEF would hit a route pattern of urlSegment1/urlSegment2.